# Create a new JSON string out of a JSON object array file - without the objects that do not containing img URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

My background is more in design and some jquery functionality but now I need to get more things done with JSON and javascript programming.

I'm getting a JSON file from a server and can not change its structure there.
Simplified it looks exactly like:

```
//JSON-File from Server:

var media = [
{"id":"978140", "name":"Star", "preview":"http://server/image5.jpg"},
{"id":"955423", "name":"Wars", "preview":"http://server/image9.jpg"},
{"id":"919752", "name":"Return" },
{"id":"924868", "preview":"http://server/image96.jpg"},
];
```

- Almost all objects of the JSON file contain the 3 key/values that i need:
  `id`, `name` and `preview`.
- (It also contains keys that i don't need like:
  `timestamp`, `publisher` and `language`.)

The big problem for me is, that not all objects contain the required `name`-key or the required `preview`-url. If I get the file and use the key/values of the objects, with the following simple jquery ajax request...:

```
//JavaScript/jQuery ajax get-request:
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: http:/serverurl.com/,
    success: function(productlist) {
        $.each(medias.media, function(key, value) {
        $mediadata.append('<li><img src="'+value.preview+'">ID: '+ value.id +' - Name: '+value.name + '</li> ');
        })
    }
});
```

... the result in the browser contains all objects (the complete displayed objects and also the **incomplete displayed objects**).

```
[IMAGE] ID: 978140 Name: Star
[IMAGE] ID: 978140 Name: Wars
[undefined] ID: 978140 Name: Return
[IMAGE] ID: 978140 Name: undefined
```

Is there a way, to clone the JSON after the get request and only extract the Objects that contain all three key/values? 
In my logic, the fastest solution to this would be something like below but I don't know enough about interaction with JSON to get this done:

```
//Possible new JavaScript/jQuery ajax get-request:
//$.ajax({
    //type: 'GET',
    //url: http:/serverurl.com/,
    //success: function(productlist) {
        //$.each(medias.media,
    where id !== undefined && name !== undefined && preview !== undefined
        //function(key, value) {
        //$mediadata.append('<li><img src="'+value.preview+'">ID: '+ value.id +' - Name: '+value.name + '</li> ');
        //})
    //}
//});
```

If there is a solution to generate a new clean JSON with only the `id`, `name` and `preview` keys for each object in JavaScript/jQuery, that would be the best help.

So there should only the "complete" objects be displayed:

```
[IMAGE] ID: 978140 Name: Star
[IMAGE] ID: 978140 Name: Wars
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Not sure mapping will work since it will map all elements, filter yes.. but than you would be doing 2 iterations throught the list: one to filter the elements and another to append them.. So choose wisely if code tiding up overpowers performance.. I would go with Shyju answer

Comment: The workload is one of my concernes but i made the script start in the background after the page is loaded and prepare the content from the JSON in hidden elements for the interaction. And the JSON is with arround 80 dynamic generated entrys long but not like too long for this ... at least i hope so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically do a null checking on properties in an if condition and use the item it passes the if condition expression.

```
$.each(media,function(a,b){

   if(b.name!=null && b.id!=null &&b.preview!=null)
   {
      $mediadata.append('<li><img src="'+b.preview+'">ID: '+ b.id +
                                                           ' - Name: '+b.name + '</li> ');
   }

});
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/yogiju/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick javascript array mapping and filter to produce a new array with only the three properties:

```
var media = [{
    "id": "978140",
    "name": "Star",
    "preview": "http://server/image5.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "955423",
    "name": "Wars",
    "preview": "http://server/image9.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "919752",
    "name": "Return"
}, {
    "id": "924868",
    "preview": "http://server/image96.jpg",
    "junk": "whatever"
}];

media = media.map(function(v) {
    if (v.id && v.name && v.preview) {
        return {
            id: v.id,
            name: v.name,
            preview: v.preview
        };
    }
}).filter(function(n) {
    return n
});

console.log(media);
```

This approach, you get a new array with just two objects and junk property is not in the new object.